# Best way to get SSID cookie from user through a discord bot

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord.js, riot-games-api

I am currently working on a discord bot that retrieves stats from the Riot games Valorant API, and for certain API access, I need their SSID cookie. One way I can obtain the cookie is through a Riot endpoint, but I need the user's username and password data. Is there any secure alternative where the user won't have to directly send their login info to my bot, or is there no other way since Riot's official OAUTH2 is private?

Comment: Does the user and pass combination matter? If not, you could try making a dummy Riot account then supplying the credentials internally

Comment: It does matter yes, the users SSID cookie corresponds to the data theyre going to get